# IO_PAGE_FAULT with new server installation

Tags: server, system-installation

In a new 20.4 server installation (5.4.0-42-generic) I am seeing many instances of the following errors during boot and intermittently on the console.

```
[  512.596563] AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=09:00.0 domain=0x0010 address=0x0 flags=0x0000]
[  548.087394] nouveau 0000:09:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0x0 flags=0x0000]
```

From lspci:

```
09:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G73 [GeForce 7600 GT] (rev 01)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried installing Ubuntu Desktop instead of Server and found that the graphics card was producing garbage output.

I replaced the card with a cheap recent model, reinstalled Server and the problem disappeared.